# BigQuery retrieve all rows where timestamp is n minutes before or after a given time of the day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a query that takes two arguments:

1. A time of the day `TIME(0, 0, 0)`
2. A number of minutes `INTERVAL 3 MINUTE`

And returns all rows where `startTime` is within the period defined as the time of the day before and after the number of minutes.

The query below works well, except when the time is midnight in which case nothing is returned.

How can I re-write this query to correctly handle this edge case, such that given above values I would get entries for 23:57, 23:58, 23:59, 00:00, 00:01, 00:02 and 00:03?

```
SELECT *
FROM data-warehouse.exchange.OHLCV_future_1m
WHERE startTime BETWEEN
  DATETIME(DATE(startTime), TIME(0, 0, 0)) - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE AND
  DATETIME(DATE(startTime), TIME(0, 0, 0)) + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE
LIMIT 100;
```

Edit 1: `startTime` is type `DATETIME`, and the data is at a minute frequency.

[image: BigQuery screenshot of startTime type]

Edit 2: added screenshot of `startTime`

[image: startTime values]

Edit 3: The following query returns 23:56:00, 23:57:00, 23:58:00 and 23:59:00

```
SELECT *
FROM data-warehouse.exchange.OHLCV_future_1m
WHERE startTime BETWEEN
  DATETIME(DATE(startTime), TIME(23, 59, 0)) - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE AND
  DATETIME(DATE(startTime), TIME(23, 59, 0)) + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: which format bhas starttime, and why if tot has the day to truncate it, besudes notz only midnughrt would give you problems also all times arounf the 3 minute intervall

Comment: Edited my post to add type of startTime, not sure I understand the rest of your comment?

Comment: time alone can't determine what you want it needs always a date part. so i asked how your data looks like. don't convert the datetime to time add and subtract 3 minutes and you will be fine, if you have no date part add it

Comment: I added another screenshot with startTime values, could you please reiterate your suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not heavily tested but hope below gives you some direction.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    DATETIME '2022-01-12 23:56:00', '2022-01-28 23:59:00', '2022-01-27 00:02:00',
             '2022-01-27 00:03:00', '2022-01-28 00:00:00', '2022-11-28 23:57:00',
             '2022-03-05 03:46:00', '2022-03-05 15:28:00', '2022-03-05 20:30:00'
  ]) startTime
)
SELECT *, time_of_the_day, interval_in_minutes,
  FROM sample_table
 WHERE DATETIME(DATE(startTime), time_of_the_day) BETWEEN startTime - interval_in_minutes AND startTime + interval_in_minutes
    OR DATETIME(DATE(startTime), time_of_the_day) + INTERVAL 1 DAY BETWEEN startTime - interval_in_minutes AND startTime + interval_in_minutes;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: This worked, thank you - before I Accept can you please explain why the OR plus one day is required?

Comment: @Charles, would you check below link for the explanation ? see https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1ise7CkD9LiOBq0D1PUuK84xmMt7w1p-hTPYvAizSvU8/edit?usp=sharing    
If still not clear, let me know again.

Answer (score 1):

You wabt a three Minute interval for a  flexible time point.

So xou should check, if the time point is midnight and remove 1 Day

```
SELECT *
FROM data-warehouse.exchange.OHLCV_future_1m
WHERE startTime BETWEEN
(CASE WHEN  TIME(0, 0, 0) =  TIME(0, 0, 0) THEN
    DATETIME(DATE(startTime), TIME(0, 0, 0)) - INTERvVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE 
  ELSE
    DATETIME(DATE(startTime), TIME(0, 0, 0))  - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE 
  END)
  AND
  DATETIME(DATE(startTime), TIME(0, 0, 0)) + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Thanks nbk, this runs but I only get 00:00:00, 00:01:00, 00:02:00 and 00:03:00